# Using curl to post encoded data from plain file to API

Tags: http, post, curl

I need to post xml data to an API and using curl seems like a good idea. That's command line curl and not curl in PHP or libcurl, at least not to start with.

The xml to post should look something like this:

```
<SearchRequest>
<LoginDetails>
<Login>******</Login>
<Password>******</Password>
<Locale></Locale>
<AgentReference></AgentReference>
</LoginDetails>
<SearchDetails>
<ArrivalDate>2016-08-01</ArrivalDate>
<Duration>2</Duration>
<RegionID>279</RegionID>
<MealBasisID>0</MealBasisID>
<MinStarRating>0</MinStarRating>
<ContractSpecialOfferID>0</ContractSpecialOfferID>
<RoomRequests>
<RoomRequest>
<Adults>2</Adults>
<Children>0</Children>
<Infants>0</Infants>
</RoomRequest>
</RoomRequests>
</SearchDetails>
</SearchRequest>
```

But it is to be posted in encoded form.

According to the specifications the complete request should look like this example:

**HTTP Post Example**

```
POST /xml/book.aspx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host servername-xml-test.somedomain.co.uk 
Content-Length 331
Expect 100-continue
Proxy-Connection Keep-Alive

Data=%3CSearchRequest%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CLoginDetails%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CLog
in%3E%3C%2FLogin...cutting out all that encoded xml here... %3C%2FSearchRequest%3E
```

So basically what I have is a URL to post to and the actual XML to post in a file (not encoded and without line breaks).

I've tried the following with only errors occurring server side (the server is outside my reach and the support is very slow so exactly what errors I cannot always say):

```
curl --header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     --header "Proxy-Connection:Keep-Alive" \
     -X POST \
     --data-binary "Data=@myfile.txt" \     
     https://server-and-domain/xml/book.aspx
```

This returns a Systems.exception. Same thing if I cange "--data-binary" to just "--data".

I've also tried:

```
curl --header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     --header "Proxy-Connection:Keep-Alive" \
     -X POST \
     --form "Data=@myfile.txt" \     
     https://server-and-domain/xml/book.aspx
```

This returns something that looks like a much more complicated error (what you get if you haven't turned off verbose errors in .net). So I guess this request is pretty far from what the server expects.

Same thing goes for `--form "Data=@myencodedfile.txt"` (but I really would prefer not having to encoded the file manually if I don't have to).

**My workaround**
I have a workaround: in "myfile.txt" I add the preceeding "Data=" and then I post it just like ascii or binary data to the URL.

```
curl --header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     --header "Proxy-Connection:Keep-Alive" \
     -X POST \
     --data-binary "@myfile.txt" \           
     https://server-and-domain/xml/book.aspx
```

However I would prefer not having to do this but keeping "myfile.txt" free from the preceding parameter name and I'm guessing that this is something that curl should be able to handle for me?

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying this...

```
curl -X POST -F "fileobj=@${file}" https://server-and-domain/xml/book.aspx
```

This successfully posts to nginx servers where attempts similar to your examples have failed.

Comment: Doing this gives me 'bad substition'. I'm actually doing: `--F "Data=@${filename}"` since the parameter should be named "Data"